# retsubkcolB Spelled Backwards

Tags: strategy

How would you enter

> retsubkcolB

spelled backwards into the comment box below and press the "Add comment" button *(nothing will happen, as there's only 11 letters)* using **at most 10 clicks** in total?

You should end up with something like this:

> [image]

Requirements:

1. **You may only use a mouse** - Right-click, left-click and cursor movement.
2. **You may only stay on this page** - Imagine this page locked into your screen. No new tabs, new windows, minimizing the current window, etc.
3. **No userscripts or extensions** - Just your standard browser on standard settings.

<sub>Note: This is a PC puzzle, so it might not work for phones.</sub>

***EDIT***

I failed to mention that you must assume this as a fresh puzzle, meaning you cannot incorporate later comments, answers, etc. into your solution.

Comment: Let me ruin the puzzle with this comment: Blockbuster ...

Comment: I failed to mention that **you must assume this as a fresh puzzle**, meaning you cannot incorporate later comments, answers, etc. into your solution.

Comment: @riskymysteries But now it turns into...well, a kind of self-referential paradox. Since your edit is a later addition to the original puzzle, that means I cannot use it (i.e. I should ignore it) in my solution.

Comment: @trolley813 Haha :D Well, I guess you could say "no copying from the edit" at least.

Comment: And one more: clipboard or something equivalent should not contain something to simplify the task, presumably should be empty before.

Comment: @z100 Yes, that's right.

Comment: Is scrolling allowed? You just said right-click, left-click, and cursor movement.

Comment: @IsaacRoanSison It's allowed :) But *only* with right-clicks, left-clicks and cursor movement. For example, using a left-click to click on the scroll bar and mouse movement to drag the bar.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is a puzzle...

Comment: @PrinceNorthLæraðr Post your answer under 10 clicks then?

Comment: __Blockbuster__

Comment: @riskymysteries what specifically was incorrect with my solution? Just curious.

Comment: @Amoz Hi! I actually really like your answer. But the accepted answer is more "solid", as it doesn't rely on anything that can be deleted/edited by fellow users. For example, I had the [riddle] tag, which got edited out by another user with an explanation.

Comment: Also, see my comment here: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/110175/retsubkcolb-spelled-backwards#comment308650_110183

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Solved in 10 moves including "Add a comment" and "Add Comment" buttons at the start and end

> (1) click on "Add a comment"
>  (2) click the "Blockquotes" option in a new answer (Blockquotes will be highlighted)
>  [image]
>  (3) press on the "flag" button (this will unhighlight Blockquotes without an extra click)
>  (4) highlight `bus`
>  [image]
>  (5) drag into comment box
>  (6) highlight `ter`
>  [image]
>  (7) drag into comment box  after `bus`
>  (8) highlight `Block`
>  [image]
>  (9) drag into comment box before `buster`
>  (10) press the "Add comment" button (nothing will happen, as there's only 11 letters)

I was muddling around in the "inspect element" for way too long trying to find something I could use in the html.

Answer (score 27):

This is hugely inspired by [*@rhavelka*'s answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/110181/13190), so make sure to upvote him/her as well!

Just found an alternative of where the phrases can come from:

> 1. Click the *Add a comment* link
>  2. Click the *Markdown Editing Help* button (the question-mark icon) in the Your Answer rich text area
>  3. Click the *Lists* help tab
>  4. Highlight 'Block' from the *Blockquotes* help tab header
>  5. Drag it into the comment box we've opened in step 1
>  6. Highlight 'bu' in the word 'bulleted' or 'bullet'
>  7. Drag it into the comment box behind the 'Block'
>  8. Highlight 'ster' in the word 'asterisk'
>  9. Drag it into the comment box behind the 'Blockbu'
>  10. Click the *Add comment* button ("*nothing will happen, as there's only 11 letters*")
>
>  Here a gif of these steps:
>  [image]

Comment: +1 definitely a cleaner solution that doesn't risk the Flag popup covering the comment box.

Comment: Hm, in my browser, when I highlight the "Block" in "Blockquotes", it automatically clicks that tab, so I am no longer in the "Lists" tab.

Comment: @justhalf What browser do you use? I personally use Chrome. And you have to start the selection just outside of the box (between the second 's' of Lists and 'B' of Blockquotes) so the cursor is still an arrow instead of hand, as you can see in the attached gif. It indeed switches to the Blockquotes tab if I start on top of the 'B' with the selection.

Comment: Ah, starting outside the box works!

Answer (score 8):

Phew finally got it in 9 I believe. Took a while to find, with help from other posters (see their post for better explanation of some shared steps)

> 1 Click add a comment to open the comment box
>  2 Press help icon on the 'New Post' box already open lower on page
>  3 Highlight 'Block' at start of 'Blockquotes' tab header of help
>  4 Drag 'Block' to original comment box
>  5 Highlight 'user' in 'No userscripts' of original post OR highlight 'User' which is found on the left side of every page
>  6 Drag 'user/User' to end of comment box
>  7 Right click left half of 'Blockuser'
>  8 Click 'Blockbuster' from the spelling context menu (verified both IE and Chrome with no extensions)
>  9 Click 'Add comment'

Comment: No spelling context menu on my browser. That's probably an extension.

Comment: Also verified in Firefox, no extensions.  What browser do you have, @WhatsUp ?

Comment: @IronEagle I use Firefox but my operating system is not English. Not sure whether the spelling context menu comes from the browser or from the operating system.

Comment: My browsers are both out of the box on brand new PCs.  Yes OS language is English; if SE help text is localized the 'accepted' answer might not work on other OS either.  If not then I guess it is "better"?

Comment: @Amoz The thing is, it makes sense for browser features to correspond to the OS, but PSE is constructed in English. It would take perhaps an Add-on or userscript to translate the PSE help text.

Answer (score 4):

A cheaty one, solved in 6 moves.

> 1. Right click on retsubkcolB.

> 2. Click on "Inspect"

> 3. Right click on the element that retsubkcolB is on right now.

> 4. Click "Delete"

> 5. Scroll to the comment box. (this counts as a click because, you can do it on your right.)

> 6. Just click on the comment box, because retsubkcolB is missing.

Comment: Interesting. But I also included that it should end up something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BitEu.png

Answer (score -2):

This is solved in five mouse clicks:

> 1. Right-click on the word "Blockbuster".
>  2. Left-click on "Copy".
>  3. Right-click on the comment box.
>  4. Left-click on "Paste".
>  5. Press the "Add comment" button (nothing will happen, as there's only 11 letters)

*Edit*: Added the final step that I missed.

Comment: I imagine the puzzle assumes that the word "Blockbuster" hasn't yet appeared on the page.

Comment: Even if it's not on the page don't you just copy letter by letter using the same steps?

Comment: Sure but that would take more than 10 clicks.

Comment: Ah missed that!

Comment: By the way, it's much easier to "drag and drop" instead of "right click - copy - right click - paste".

Comment: Yeah that works in 9 steps with drag and drop if you drag "B", "lock", "ust", and "er" found in body text

Comment: Er I spelled it wrong but I'm sure someone'll sort it out

Comment: I guess it's B lock bu and ster, found those, think that's spelled right now

Comment: @Amoz You should post your own answer, I think.

Comment: Drag and drop doesn't seem to work on my macbook but I assume that's the correct approach, looks like @Amoz got it.

Comment: Also "ster" only appears in the OP's username, which is almost impossible to select (at least on my browser).

Comment: I agree ster isn't selectable. Probably some way to grab all the text between "B" and "browser" and cut out the irrelevant parts, because Blockbuster is clearly embedded in there. Not seeing it offhand, cutting is taking me too many clicks

Comment: @hexomino If we are allowed for five pieces, then there are many solutions. However it is mentioned "and press the "Add comment" button" so this should also count as one click.

Comment: Hi, I made an edit. Not bad though, but did you forget to add the "Add *a* comment" step, which counts for another click? Also, are you able to right click on the word without highlighting it first?

Comment: "steries" is selectable starting from behind.

Comment: Yes, you're able to highlight a word with a single right-click (at least on Mac).